# Error while using 'fitQmap' function in 'qmap' package in R

Tags: r, qmap

While using the `fitQmap` function in the R package `qmap`, I'm getting the follow error:

```
x <- c(2179.759, 2154.498, 2130.792, 2173.525, 2121.694, 2110.078, 2112.477, 2080.512, 2074.096, 2133.571, 2146.682, 2132.320, 2139.447, 2134.702, 2172.010, 2192.373, 2181.527, 2129.207, 2162.051, 2152.892, 2153.572, 2100.184, 2097.798, 2081.844, 2152.124, 2150.993, 2154.406, 2153.052, 2165.105, 2160.334, 2167.217, 2132.754, 2132.047, 2166.314, 2144.134, 2158.401, 2150.392, 2142.335)

y <- c(1573.643, 1508.386, 1473.686, 1487.429, 1492.271, 1534.929, 1509.957, 1510.229, 1558.500, 1532.629,1575.000, 1601.800, 1600.200, 1608.600, 1643.629, 1561.229, 1610.814, 1552.329, 1497.243, 1452.200, 1439.743, 1405.829, 1424.600, 1387.186, 1423.771, 1461.429, 1522.871, 1565.757, 1560.657, 1593.514, 1647.829, 1645.186, 1635.371, 1595.057, 1566.043, 1547.929, 1496.543, 1479.057)

fit <- fitQmap(y, x, method=c('DIST'))

[1] "Error in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,  : \n  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth, lower = lower,     upper = upper, ...): L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'>
Error in fitQmapDIST.default(obs, mod, ...) : 
  'mledist' failed to estimate parameters for 'mod' with the error code 100
```

Why this is happening and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try with sqrt function

```
fit <- fitQmap(sqrt(y), sqrt(x), method=c('DIST'))
corr <- doQmap(sqrt(x),fit)^2
```